# How to prove/verify the following inequality consisting of polynomial and exponential holds?

Tags: inequality

How to verify the inequation $C^{H}e^{-\lambda^2 C} \leq \delta$ holds for $C = \frac{1}{\lambda^{2}} (2H log \frac{H}{\lambda^2} + log\frac{1}{\delta})$? Namely, we treat $H \geq 1$, $\lambda > 0$, and $\delta > 0$ as constants and $C$ as the variable.

Furthermore, can we provide a general condition of C under which the inequation will hold?

To provide some context, this inequation is a simplified version of Eq (17) in paper [A Sparse Sampling Algorithm for Near-Optimal
Planning in Large Markov Decision Processes](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~mkearns/papers/sparsesampling-journal.pdf) with $V_{max} = 1$ and $K=1$. By proving this inequation, we are able to show Theorem 1 in that paper is correct and thus the "sparse sampling algorithm" is indead "near-optimal".

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide some context of this question. Why do you want to prove this inequality?

Comment: @HoldingArthur I modify the original problem statement and add the context showing the significance of this inequality. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that $\log$ means $\log_e$. Then my calculations shows that the claim can be wrong. Indeed,

$$C^{H}e^{-\lambda^2 C}=\left(\frac{1}{\lambda^{2}}\left(2H \log \frac{H}{\lambda^2} + \log\frac{1}{\delta}\right)\right)^H e^{-2H\log \frac{H}{\lambda^2} - \log\frac{1}{\delta}}=$$
$$\left(\frac{1}{\lambda^{2}}\left(2H \log \frac{H}{\lambda^2} + \log\frac{1}{\delta}\right)\right)^H \left(\frac{H}{\lambda^2}\right)^{-2H}\delta=$$
$$\left(\frac{\lambda^2}{H^2}\left(2H \log \frac{H}{\lambda^2} + \log\frac{1}{\delta}\right)\right)^H\delta.$$

If $H=\lambda^2$ then $C^{H}e^{-\lambda^2 C}=(\log\frac 1{\delta})^H\delta$. It can be bigger than $\delta$, for instance, when $H=1$ and $\delta=\frac 1{e^2}$.

> can we provide a general condition of C under which the inequation will hold?

Since $0^He^{-\lambda^2 0}=0$, by the continuity of the left hand side, the inequality $C^{H}e^{-\lambda^2 C}\le\delta$ holds for sufficiently small $C$. To satisfy the inequality it suffices to take any $0<C\le 1$ such that $ e^{-\lambda^2 C}\le\delta$, that is $- C\le\frac{\log\delta}{\lambda^2}$.

Comment: Thanks so much for your comments on this old question. Actually, later after I post this question, I manage to find a proof and write in a [note](https://mickeystroller.github.io/resources/CS598NJ/report.pdf) (Eq. 18 -- 23) after Colloary 1 and before lemma 3. I will double-check your answer and return to you in these two days. Thanks again for your time.

Comment: @MickeyJ.Shen In line 22 you use an additional assumption $\tfrac 1{\delta}<\tfrac H{\lambda}$, which is violated in my counterexample (but it was not provided in the question).

Comment: Thanks for your comments and you are right. I have accepted your answer and highlight your comments. Thanks again.